# Problem with c# events

Tags: c#, .net, events

I need to implement Pause and Resume events of a MP3 player inside the same button click event. following is the code i have tried and its not working,Can any one give me the solution

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button3.Text == "Pause")
    {
        CommandString = "pause mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        Status = true;
        button3.Text = "Resume";           
    }
    if (button3.Text == "Resume")
    {   
        CommandString = "resume mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? The `if` condition is not verified or the `mciSendString` function? If it's the `mciSendString` function you will have to describe what this function is, where it comes from, what it is supposed to do, etc...

Comment: Have you considered implementing a state machine?

Comment: *"it's not working"* is unfortunately not very helpful for us. Can you be more specific? Do you get errors? Does the pause work, but not the resume, or the other way around? Do the buttons fail, or the MP3? Exceptions, crashes? What happens when you place a breakpoint in the event handler, is it hit and does the execution follow the path you expect?

Comment: It appears that depending on the text on the button you decide which state your MP3 player is in. Whether or not this is a wise choice is a different question but it would be helpful to understand what `mciSendString()` does. I also agree with previous comments: "It's not working." isn't specific enough to provide good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are changing the button3.Text property within the first if statement.
When the second if statement is tested it is true (both if statements are running with each button click when the Text property is "Pause")

Use if, else to run one code block or another.

Use if, else if  statements if you want a test to be run on the second code block also.

You should also take account of the possibility that neither of these cases is true.

```
if (button3.Text == "Pause")
{
    CommandString = "pause mp3file";
    mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
    Status = true;
    button3.Text = "Resume";
}
else if(button3.Text == "Resume")
{   
    CommandString = "resume mp3file";
    mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
    button3.Text = "Pause";
}
```

Comment: +1 for good advice (but missed the change back to "Pause" though)

Answer (score 4):

at first glance it won't work properly 'cause in 2 case

```
if (button3.Text == "Resume")
{   
    CommandString = "resume mp3file";
    mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
}
```

you missed the line:

```
button3.Text = "Pause";
```

Actually it's not a good idea to check the button state by its text property. As a simple solution you need to have a boolean flag to check against it.

Comment: Ah... I missed that, but noticed the two if statements

Comment: @Lewray it's not you but the author :)

Answer (score 1):

you have two if consecutive if statements. You need just one if/else statement.

change your code to:

```
    if (button3.Text == "Pause")
    {
        CommandString = "pause mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        Status = true;
        button3.Text = "Resume";           
    }
    else if (button3.Text == "Resume")
    {   
        CommandString = "resume mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

By the time you get to the second if statement, you have changed the Text of the button, hence both statements are being run...

Here is a quick test:

```
        if (button1.Text == "Pause")
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text + " saw pause ";
            button1.Text = "Resume";


        }
        if (button1.Text == "Resume")
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text + " saw resume ";
            button1.Text = "Pause";
        }
```

returns: label1 saw pause saw resume.

There are two ways to fix this:

You could insert a 'return;' statement within each if statement:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (button3.Text == "Pause")
    {
        CommandString = "pause mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        Status = true;
        button3.Text = "Resume";
        return;
    }
    if (button3.Text == "Resume")
    {   
        CommandString = "resume mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        button3.Text = "Pause";
        return;
    }
}
```

Or secondly, you could capture the value of the button text once:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String value = button3.Text;
    if (value == "Pause")
    {
        CommandString = "pause mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        Status = true;
        button3.Text = "Resume";

    }
    if (value == "Resume")
    {   
        CommandString = "resume mp3file";
        mciSendString(CommandString, null, 0, 0);
        buton3.Text = "Pause"; // As mentioned before, this is required too.
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Steve